# how to set up a first person character controller's movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to make a first person character controller for a game im making, it wont need jumping nor fast speeds or any additional moves, practically just walking and a weapon swinging ill add down the line, right now though first person is out of my comfort zone, i made a third person character controller and it wasnt THIS difficult, im basically trying to change the forward vector of the player capsule into something more compatable with input.getaxis, i currently have a frankenstien mess that hardly functions, but the camera movement functions just fine, with my current setup i am using a rigidbody to control the player, and i idealy want to use velocity and not addforce or moveposition, velocity has given me the best results so far, how can i fix my movement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class characterController : MonoBehaviour {
    //variables and functions
    public float moveSpeed = 0.1f;
    public bool tweening = false;
    public bool jumping = false;
    public bool reteleporing = false;
    bool walking = false;
    public bool ragdolled = false;
    public Vector3 smoothedvel;
    public Vector3 smoothedrotationalvector;
    public Vector3 cameraoffset;
    void Start () {
        cameraoffset = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        smoothedvel = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        moveSpeed = 5;
    }
    
    void Update (){
        //movement
        smoothedrotationalvector = Vector3.Lerp(smoothedrotationalvector, new Vector3(-Input.GetAxis("Vertical"),0,Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")), 0.2f);
        if (new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"),0,Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")).magnitude != 0)
        {
            transform.LookAt(GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position, -Vector3.up);
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,transform.localEulerAngles.y,0);
        }
        if (transform.position.y < -100)
        {
            reteleporing = true;
        }
        if (reteleporing == true)
        {
            transform.position = GameObject.Find("spawnpos").transform.position;
        }
        if (transform.position.y > 2.4)
        {
            reteleporing = false;
        }
        if (reteleporing == false)
        {
            if (new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"),0,Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")).magnitude != 0)
            {
                float axisX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
                float axisZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;

                Vector3 moveDirection = transform.right * axisX + transform.forward * axisZ;

                gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = moveDirection;
            }
        }
        if (new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"),0,Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")).magnitude != 0 & walking == false)
        {
            walking = true;
        }
        if (new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"),0,Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")).magnitude == 0 & walking == true)
        {
            walking = false;
        }
        GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position = transform.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Despite all the redundancies and expensive things in your code  (`GetAxis` five times instead of cashing the value once, expensive usage of `Find` again without cashing the result **once**, the `telepoerting` and `walking` flags...) what exactly is the issue with your code? What is not behaving as expected?

Comment: And btw why don't you simply make the Camera a child of your player object -> it will be moved along automatically

Comment: And you know that Unity already **has** a [`CharacterController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html) component .. why not simply use that one?

Comment: well to adress a couple of things, i simply want advice as how i can make a good character controller for first person from ground up, i looked on youtube and i cant seem to find what im looking for (a first person character controller that uses rigidbody velocity, not addforce like people tend to post, or moveposition like people also post) please keep in mind i am a beginner so i will optimize the code in the future, i dont use the character controller component because i want as much controll as is practical for game developement

Comment: heres a couple things i want to know, to narrow down what i want: i want to know how i can use getaxis with velocity while doing it relative to the camera, if you took the time to test some of my code you would see that it technically does do that, its just awful and barely functional, basically want some advice on how i can "fix" my code to make it actually function, when you walk forward you walk forward, when you walk backward you walk forward, when you walk off an edge you hover because i didnt account for velocity.y (i dont know how) and other issues i can fix myself

Comment: will definitely try to go optimize my code more, its practically my 3rd person character controller code that was messed around with to make it somewhat function in first person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it, i used addforce instead of velocity and messed around with it from there, turns out velocity is really bad for things like this, it just downright didnt work because of velocity alone from what i can tell, another somewhat major thing was the switch from getaxis to getaxisraw, made it alot more snappy.